# Help with formula field:

Tags: formula, formula-field

Below formula count 1 when statement is true and count 0 when statement is false.

I am using this formula to calculate bad data populated being populated in lead object.

Output of this formula is number

My problem is that this formula is not giving me the right count. There is no Syntax error.

```
( 
IF(AND( 
NOT(ISBLANK(FirstName)), 
LEN(FirstName) < 3), 1, 0) + 


IF(AND( 
NOT(ISBLANK(LastName)), 
LEN(LastName) < 3), 1, 0) + 


IF (AND( 
NOT (ISBLANK(Company)), 
LEN(Company) < 3), 1, 0) + 


IF(AND( 
NOT(ISBLANK(Phone)), 
LEN(Phone) < 10), 1, 0) + 

IF(AND( 
NOT(ISBLANK(Email)), 
LEN(Email) < 5), 1, 0) + 

IF(AND( 
NOT (ISBLANK(Title)), 
LEN(Title) < 2), 1, 0) + 

IF (AND ( 
NOT (ISBLANK(Website)), 
LEN(Website) < 5), 1, 0) + 

IF (AND ( 
NOT (ISBLANK(Street)), 
LEN(Street) < 3), 1, 0) + 

IF (AND ( 
NOT (ISBLANK(PostalCode)), 
LEN(PostalCode) < 5), 1, 0) 
) 
/ No_of_Key_Fields_Populated__c
```

Comment: I think seeing some sample input, the output you're currently getting, and the output you're expecting might help.

Comment: What is `No_of_Key_Fields_Populated__c`? And when you say it's not giving you the right count, can you specify? List out a Lead's field values, what you'd expect your formula to return, and what it does return. Please edit your quetion to include these details.

Comment: CONTD.. @DerekF ,Thomas -  above fomula in question the result should be 1 as only one filed email has more than 5 length. Problem is my output is always one for this even it can have more fields populated and also length of a field is more than it needs to be.

Comment: How is your formula field set up? Does it have decimal places? And also Thomas's question, what is No_of_Key_Fields_Populated__c?

Comment: The formula looks right to me. Why do you not try out the formula with your data step by step, so that you can see for every if statement that you are getting the right result and modify accordingly if not?

Comment: @user40501. This worked. Its the data not formula . Thank you everyone.